# Laravel Eloquent: Inverse of Many To Many (Polymorphic)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Example copied from official Laravel Docs:

For example, a Post model and Video model could share a polymorphic relation to a Tag model. Using a many-to-many polymorphic relation in this situation would allow your application to have a single table of unique tags that may be associated with posts or videos. First, let's examine the table structure required to build this relationship:

```
posts
id - integer
name - string

videos
id - integer
name - string

tags
id - integer
name - string

taggables
tag_id - integer
taggable_id - integer
taggable_type - string
```

From a tag object I wanted to get all the videos and posts, to which that subjected tag belongs (in case of morphOne an morphMany I can do that by morphTo() method)

Laravel says, I need to define both the videos and posts methods in Tag model in order to define an inverse but I want a relation like taggables which will return the respected parent (whether it's Post or Video)

[image]

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship)

I need a similar thing like imageable (but it is polymorphic one to one and I need this kind of thing in many to many)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `MorphOne`/`MorphMany` in your pivot model.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

```
class Video extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->using(Taggable::class);
    }

    public function taggables()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Taggable::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->using(Taggable::class);
    }

    public function taggables()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Taggable::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable')->using(Taggable::class);
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'taggable')->using(Taggable::class);
    }

    public function taggables()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Taggable::class/*, 'tag_id'*/)
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class Taggable extends MorphPivot
{
    public $incrementing = false; // this is the default value. Change if you need to.
    public $guarded = [];         // this is the default value. Change if you need to.
    protected $table = 'taggables';

    public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class/*, 'tag_id'*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been search for something like a week for this! Thank you so much @IGP !!!